# Text widget detects a Real Time Fireabase value as null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch these values from my real time database and put them in my `Text` widget i have successfully retrieved them in my app the only problem is making them usable in my `Text` widget

[image]

These are the text widgets which i want to use thhe fetch `String` from the real time database

**FIRST TEXT WIDGET**

```
Text(
    getSnapShotData('orders_count'),//here is the function being run
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 16,
      fontFamily: "Sofia_Pro",
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    ),
  ),
```

**SECOND TEXT WIDGET**

```
Text(
    getSnapShotData('name'),//here is the function being run
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 16,
      fontFamily: "Sofia_Pro",
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    ),
  ),
```

**FUNCTION TO FETCH FROM THE REAL TIME DATABSE**

```
String getSnapShotData(String child){
 databaseReference.child("users").child(_firebaseUser.uid).child(child).once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  var foo = snapshot.value;
  var fooString = snapshot.value.toString();
  
  print(snapshot.value);
  print("type is ${foo.runtimeType}");
  print("type is ${fooString.runtimeType}");
  
  return fooString;
  });
}
```

The funny thing is that if i log the values fetched i get normal results thhe only problem comes when i use the fetched data into `Text` widget

**THIS IS THE LOG RESULT OF FETCHED DATA**

```
  I/flutter (29458): 4
  I/flutter (29458): type is int
  I/flutter (29458): type is String
```

Comment: `getSnapShotData` always returns immediately, and never returns any value to the caller of the function.  The return statement you have now just returns a value from the asynchronous `then` callback, which is not the same as returning a value from the the function which contains it.  The snapshot data in the callback is effectively trapped within that callback.  You might want to consider using a FutureBuilder to set up a query that will eventually populate your view when the data becomes available.

Comment: kindly show me a code sample